# Why does my system power off suddenly?

Tags: windows

I am using desktop with intel dual core processor on biostar motherboard. Now days,after 1 hour working(not exact) it suddenly power off(not shut down) with out warning.when i try to power it on,some time it woks for few minutes and again power off and some time it  start for 2 or 3 second and power off(before booting). can any one help me to identify and fix this issue??

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of things can cause this such as:

1- Check if the CPU fan is working fine

2- Check if viruses found in your PC.

3- Check your electricity cable.

Comment: 1. b) check the CPU temperature isn't climbing too high

Answer (score 1):

Are you living in India or where electricity reliability is poor? If yes, on my recent visit I noticed several thousand volt surges in power supply (frying two motherboards and one PSU). So, do you have a good voltage stabilizer or Uninterrupted Power Supply?

Second, if you assembled the PC, did you use high quality CPU grease (Thermal compound) like Artic5 or like that?

Third, do you have simple fan or a cooling tower on CPU?

If any one of this is correct, I am guessing that you have a misconfigured PC setup, including corrupt BIOS, motherboard or CPU temp sensor.

You can monitor CPU temp with CPUz or Sandra Lite (NOTE: I am note endorsing any product mentioned herein)
http://www.filehippo.com/software/system_tuning/
http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/

Also, it is possible that your Power Supply Unit is not able to provide enough power for dual core CPU. You should have at least 650W PSU, may be 750W. Do you have top notch GPU? If so, it is drawing more power that CPU goes without power (may be a few hundredth of millisecond).